# AngularJS ui-mask optional characters are not really optional

Tags: angularjs

I have a database that holds 10-digit local fax numbers in this format 9999999999, where the first 3 digits has the area code, and the rest is the fax number.

The database also has some 11-digit fax numbers with a 1 in front for long distance faxes: 19999999999.

My html page has an input with ui-mask="?9 (999) 999-9999"
The first character is optional.

But when I run the web page, it forces me to enter the first optional digit. I cannot place the cursor inside the first parentheses for local fax numbers.
I don't need to enter the 1 when it is a local fax number.
I read that the AngularJS ui-mask uses a ? for an optional character but this is not true.

How can we leave the first optional digit as blank?